# Stirling's formula

Tags: probability

Could anyone help me to solve this exercise?

Using Stirling's formula show that
$${n \choose k}= \frac 1{(2πn \frac k{n}(1- \frac kn))^{1/2}}e^{n S(\frac kn)}(1+O(n^{(-1/2)},k^{-1/2},(n-k)^{-1/2}))$$
Where $S(x)=-x \ln x-(1-x) \ln(1-x), 0 \le x \le 1$.

I used n!=$e^{(-n)}n^{(n+1/2)}(2π)^{1/2}(1+O(1/n))$ and my result is 
$$ \frac {(1+O(1/n))e^{n S(\frac kn)}}{(2πn \frac kn(1- \frac kn))^{1/2}(1+O(1/k))(1+O(1/(n-k)))}$$

Is this equal to the result I have to show??

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format your questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Comment: Welcome!  Here's [how to ask a homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).  Also, please don't write things like "SOS" in the title; it is annoying and messes up searching.